# Solve $a^2=b+c^2$ with integers

Tags: problem-solving, integer-programming

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to solve $a^2=b+c^2$ for $a$ and $c$ when $b$ is given, and all three variables are integers greater than $0$.  I know that because there are two variables, there may be infinite solutions.  I would prefer to get the lowest possible positive integer values of $a$ and $c$ that make the equation true.  I can solve this with trial and error, but there must be a faster way.

Answer (score 2):

When $b$ is given, you have $a^2=b+c^2$, which you can rearrange to find $(a+c)(a-c)=b$, so you need to look for the factors of $b$ where the two numbers in the product differ by an even number (the even number is $2c$).

Comment: But how would I "look for the factors" of $b$ when $b$ is a number like $2938472933791791$?  I can't possibly plug in random numbers until it works.  Is there any faster way?

Comment: Unfortunately, for this method, you would have to factor it. On the other hand, if you want just any $a$ and $c$, you know that $(a+1)^2-a^2=2a+1$, $(a+2)^2-a^2=4a+4$, and generally that $(a+n)^2-a^2=2an+n^2=n(2a+n)$. I point this out specifically because if $b$ is a large odd number as above, you can try $2a+1=b$ and find an appropriate $a$ and $c=a+1$. If $b$ is divisible by $4$, you can solve $4a+4=b$ and use $a$ and $a+2$. You may end up encountering the same issue with requiring some factorization here, since for a general $n$, you need $n$ to divide $b$, since $(a+n)^2-a^2=n(2a+n)$.